# Architectural analysis of an existing project

Tags: architecture, project-management, code-analysis, static-analysis

I would like to ask for an advice in question of architectural analysis of an existing project. We are going to be involved in an existing project, but as a first thing we should create an analysis of it. (Architecture, code, strengths, weaknesses, patterns, code duplication and static code analysis etc.) My question is whether you know about any books, articles, tools for analysis, any materials dealing with this topic? It will be cool if I would be able to see any example of this kind of report.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a bout a specific programming task or tool - it may be more relevant on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) server.

It contains lots of plugins for static analysis, code quality (Findbugs, PMD, Checkstyle, ...) and test coverage (cobertura). There are also plugins for architectural analysis (e.g. [sonarj](https://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sonarj/sonar) with the so called "structural debt index"). Please note, that some plugins are commercial but most are free. Also the server is not only for Java but for many different [languages](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Languages).

In our experience the sonar server configured with the right [plugins](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java-specific+Plugins) is way better than many of the available commercial solutions.

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer: I am part of the Dev team of the quoted tool*

If you are working with .NET code the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) can help you analyze your code base architecture. The tool proposes an interactive [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph) that works with an interactive [dependency structure matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm) (DSM).

Also a code query language is provided to query the code architecture (like asking which namespaces depends on a particular assembly) and also write architecture code rules (like for example [UI layer shouldn't use directly DB layer](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html?Q_UI_layer_shouldn%27t_use_directly_DB_types.html)).

Concerning code, strengths, weaknesses, patterns, and static code analysis, NDepend comes with around [200 default code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/webframe.html) on these various topics (that can be easily customized).

Concerning code duplication, a side [OSS power tools](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2012/06/12/an-original-algorithm-to-find-net-code-duplicate/) based on [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/api/webframe.html) is proposed.

The tool is integrated in Visual Studio 2008/2010/2012/2013 and also can be integrated in the build process to output some [HTML+js reports](http://www.ndepend.com/sample-reports/).

---

Here is what looks like some code architecture visualized through the NDepend dependency graph:
[image: NDepend Dependency Graph]

Here what looks like some code architecture visualized through the NDepend dependency matrix:
[image: NDepend Dependency Matrix]